# Automatically include Entity Framework properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

the answer to my question might be trivial, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Suppose, we have the following situation:

### A DB first EF-Entity with nested Properties:

```cs
public partial class Employee
{
     public int ID { get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<EmployeeDepartmentHistory> EmployeeDepartmentHistory { get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<JobCandidate> JobCandidate { get; set;}
}
```

### A Domain Class `Employee`

(related classes don't matter for this example)

```cs
public class Employee
{
     public int ID { get; set;}
     public IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set;}
     public IEnumerable<JobCandidate> Candidates { get; set;}
}
```

### A Service Class `EmployeeService` that applies business rules to the query

```cs
public class EmployeeService
    private RepoTestEntities1 _Database;

    public EmployeeService(RepoTestEntities1 database)
    {
        _Database = database;
    }

    public IQueryable<DomainModels.Employee> GetSalariedEmployeesByDepartmentName(string departmentName)
    {
        _Database.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return _Database.Employee
            .Include(e => e.EmployeeDepartmentHistory)
            .Include(e => e.JobCandidate)
            .Include(e => e.EmployeeDepartmentHistory.Select(his => his.Department))
            .AsNoTracking()
            .WhereDepartmentName(departmentName)
            .WhereSalariedFlag(true)
            .Select(e => CreateEmployee(e));
    }
    private DomainModels.Employee CreateEmployee(Employee e)
    {
        [...] (transform to domain)
    }
```

`WhereDepartmentName` and `WhereSalariedFlag` are implemented as extension methods to `IQueryable<Employee>`.

### Now to the question

---

Suppose I need further methods, that retrieve Employees from DbContext and I don't want to use Lazy loading.

Repeatedly calling all those includes is redundant, error prone and tedious. Do you know an elegant way of always including the needed properties for all methods of the `EmployeeService` ?

Might a strategy pattern be a viable approach?

Comment: No. Don't do that. Don't include all your navigational properties into your entities. Just retrieve what you want. If it is the fear of error prone so just unit test all implemented methods.

Comment: You might look at creating an extension method or using automapper: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30839/dbsett-includeall-method

Comment: You could also expose different properties that simply return the DbSet with all Includes. However, as @CodeNotFound mentioned, having all navigation properties eagerly loaded usually is a huge performance hit and may make your BL more error prone.

Comment: Prefer explicit loading over lazy loading.

Comment: @CodeNotFound and DevilSuichiro: As I am consolidating the associated entities any way in the domain class I don't think that this is an performance hit. Especially if, instead of loading the navigation properties initially, i'm lazy loading all associated properties on their own which means a db hit on every property. 
Why would it make my BL more error prone ?!.
Steve Greenes comment is pointing a good direction.

Comment: You could write an extension that would include all properties which are `ICollection<>` passing property name instead of lambda accessor.

However, as others suggested, this may cause you some serious performance pain troubleshooting which would cause a few gray hairs, so i'd use with caution

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY need to Include all the navigation properties you can use this piece of code.
If you need to eagerly load also collections (not always a good idea) you can delete the continue statement in the code.
Context is your context (`this` if you insert this code in your context)

```
    public IQueryable<T> IncludeAllNavigationProperties<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable)
    {
        if (queryable == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("queryable");

        ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext;
        var metadataWorkspace = ((EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection).GetMetadataWorkspace();

        EntitySetMapping[] entitySetMappingCollection = metadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace).Single().EntitySetMappings.ToArray();

        var entitySetMappings = entitySetMappingCollection.First(o => o.EntityTypeMappings.Select(e => e.EntityType.Name).Contains(typeof(T).Name));

        var entityTypeMapping = entitySetMappings.EntityTypeMappings[0];

        foreach (var navigationProperty in entityTypeMapping.EntityType.NavigationProperties)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(navigationProperty.Name);
            if (propertyInfo == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("propertyInfo == null");
            if (typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType))
                continue;

            queryable = queryable.Include(navigationProperty.Name);
        }

        return queryable;
    }
```